# IntelliJ and Eclipse gives different result

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

For some reason my project gives the below error in eclipse:

[image]

No error in IntelliJ. Any ideas?

Using IntelliJ:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IC-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2 x86
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Comment: My IntelliJ version reports an error. Maybe you have an old one.

Comment: Using latest version of IntelliJ, see updated post.

Comment: Well, the two keys are on a yellow background, which indicates an inspection error. Hover your mouse, and you'll see `Object contains duplicate keys "//"`

Comment: You are right, why is that treated as a warning in IntelliJ and as an error in Eclipse? Or am I misinterpreting IntelliJ markers?

Comment: Why?  Because the IDE's are different?  You can most likely set either behavior in either.  Time to dive into the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind different results is that ***Different IDEs use different inspection tools***.

In your particular question **Eclipse** shows an **error**, while **Intellij** shows a **warning**. So anyhow both are suggesting that ***something has gone wrong*** here.

Besides it's a warning or an error, the point both are making is ***Not to use key duplication in json***. The reason is when you refers the ***value via the key*** then ***key duplication causes problems***.

Since ***JSON*** is just a ***markup language*** and ***creates no problems for project build***, **Intellij** would just make a **warning** and not an error. Since ***key duplication does make no sense though,*** **Eclipse** would mark up as an **error**. Anyway not to worry about whether warning or error, just catch the point they are making. :))